# Large XML file ( >16 Mb) Parsing?

Tags: apex, trigger, string

I have an requirement for Large XML file (>16 Mb) Parsing.

Getting error :
Error uploading attachment:Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AttachmentManagmentTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: String length exceeds maximum: 6000000 Class.parseXMLClass.loadXML: line 23, column 1 Trigger.AttachmentManagmentTrigger: line 6, column 1: []

At : String bodyContent = .body.toString();

Any help!!

Comment: You're probably going to need to leverage an external service. Maybe build your own on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I don't think there is anything you can do to process a document that large on salesforce directly. You'll need some external system to do some data parsing and pass smaller requests into salesforce.

Even if you were able to split it into multiple strings you'll still likely exceed the heap space [governing limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) with that one file if you try to manipulate it all in one request.